# Creating a resizing gui button not working Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scaling

So guys I,m trying to create a program for writing a little text file.
After some testing, I saw that the GUI is too large for people with a lesser resolution than Full-HD.
So I decided to create a button that changes the scaling of the program but it doesn't work.
Here is the code

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import colorama
import requests
colorama.init()
root = Tk()
root.title('Test')

def done():
    print("test")

def downscale():
    root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 0.5)
    print("Downscaling should be working!")

downscale = Button(root, text='Can you see the done button?', command=downscale)
downscale.grid(row=1, column=1)

b = Button(root, text='Done', command=run)
b.grid(row=50, column=50)

root.mainloop()
```

It's important to know that If I use "root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 0.5)"
in the script normally without a function it works.

Comment: Why not just design the GUI to fit in the current display no matter what the resolution? Tkinter is very good at calculating window sizes. There is almost certainly a better solution than changing the scaling factor to an incorrect value.

Comment: what can I use for this do you have any examples?

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve] of a program that works well on a high resolution device but doesn't work well on a low resolution device. Unless we know why your program isn't working, it's hard to offer suggestions.

Comment: I just want to know how to use the resizing button I don't want to use any other methods. The program is also working but on smaller resolutions it some buttons just don't show.
So I want to do the resize button or give me an example on how to use the calculation feature in tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Try geometry and winfo_screennwidth() and winfo_screenheight it works as long as the screen is unzoomed state

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import colorama
import requests
colorama.init()
root = Tk()
root.title('Test')

def done():
    print("test")

def downscale():
    try:
        root.state('normal')
    except:root.attributes('-zoomed', False)
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(root.winfo_width()//2,root.winfo_height()//2))

downscale = Button(root, text='Can you see the done button?', command=downscale)
downscale.grid(row=1, column=1)

b = Button(root, text='Done')
b.grid(row=50, column=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the code you have added did nothing. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: @Mr_Oliver whenever I press the can you see.. button the size of the root window reduces by half. Maybe it works only for windows